# How do I automatically create links to directories?

Tags: file-sharing, users, symbolic-link

What is the easiest/quickest way to share files among different users?

I would like each user to have access to the same music and pictures directories. Creating symbolic links seems tedious as I would have to manually add them after I created each user.

Is there a way to automatically create links to these directories for each user?

Comment: I presume you mean users on the same machine, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write use below mentioned shell script to create links for those directories for existing users and could use [skel](http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html) so that links are automatically created when new users are added.

```
#!/bin/bash

# GENERATES ALL THE USER HOMES
USERSHOMES="$(cat /etc/passwd | grep home | grep -v /bin/false | cut -d: -f6)"

# THIS IS THE LINK NAME
LINK="music-dir"

# LINK DIRECTORY TO ALL HOMES
for h in $USERSHOMES
do

   # WHERE YOU WANT TO COPY TO
   _dir="${h}/Desktop"
   if [ -d "$_dir" ]
   then
      ln -s "/media/music" "$_dir/$LINK"
   fi
done
```

Tested on my system.